# How to convert disk from thin to thick in VMWare ESXi 6.5.0 Web UI?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm trying to convert a virtual disk from thin to thick provisioning by following instructions in https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-E8F50BEC-F575-4AB1-BC77-D9A13CDBDCF7.html

However, when I right click the .vmdk in the datastore browser, I can see options "Delete", "Download", "Move" and "Copy" but no "Inflate".

How to inflate a disk using the Web UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution: Updated to ESXi version 6.5.0 Update 1 and the "Inflate" option is now available in th

Answer (score 0):

The reason you only see those options is because you're on the web UI, the instructions you posted are for VSphere. I don't think you can do what you want to do without vSphere. Disk options are quite limited on the Web UI (I don't use vSphere either).

However if you can shut the VMs down, can't you create a new thick disk and copy things across manually? That's probably occurred to you already but I can't be sure, and it's the only solution I can think of for you.

(This is my first ever SF answer, sorry if it isn't entirely helpful!)

Comment: In 6.5 the support for the vSphere Client was dropped. There is only the WebUI (well, two of them).